# Can't Get .preventDefault() to work

Tags: javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".recaptchaButton").click(function(event) {
            var recaptchaHidden = true;
            if (recaptchaHidden == true) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $(".recaptcha").css("display","block");
                recaptchaHidden = false;
            }
        });
    </script>
```

I have no idea why event.preventDefault(); isn't working in the above script. It's on the website buybluesky.com if you need a wider picture. The code looks absolutely fine to me.

Comment: `recaptchaHidden` will always be `true` and you can't access it outside, what's that for?

Comment: To detect whether or not to try to submit the form. That's not why it's not working, so it's irrelevant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might also want to stop propagation, depending on what the behavior is. You might not be triggering default browser behavior, but actually passing the event up the DOM to another handler. I always `return false` from events I want to stop right then and there.

That is equivalent to `e.stopPropagation()` AND `e.preventDefault()`

To clarify: from an event handler in javascript, if the callback returns false then bubbling stops AND the default behavior (form submit or anchor href following) is prevented.

Comment: also, events are triggered in the order they are added. if there is another event attached to this before you do it, that will execute first

Comment: That's fixed it, thank you. Usually preventDefault() works just fine, not sure what the differnce is.

Comment: That's a great point. If there's already another handler on it and you need to jump ahead in the queue, look into native DOM nethods that handle 'capturing': http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3137-using-event-capturing-to-improve-basecamp-page-load-times

Comment: Rev, preventDefault will stop the BROWSER behavior from occurring: link following, form submitting, etc. What was likely happening was that there was another event handler that was being triggered. When the event happens at (childNode1), a handler there will run, and after that the event propagates up the DOM tree to (childNode2) to see if there were handlers there too. e.stopPropagation() OR return false stop that propagation/bubbling.